# How do I make the clock stop chiming every hour on the hour?

Tags: sound, 11.10, gnome, clock

I'm using a fully updated 11.10 install.  After I installed the gnome-shell 3.2 package the clock started chiming every hour (it sounds like a doorbell).  If I'm listening to something that needs to be turned up loud...well you get the idea.  It's annoying to say the least.

Disabling system sounds does NOT stop it.  I can not find anything in gsettings or dconf/gconf-editor.  Is there any one out there with a fix before I go crazy?

Comment: I think gnome shell does not use gconf any more. Maybe you find something in the `~/.local` dir.

Comment: Have you checked your grandfather clock? :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was not GNOME Shell at all.  It is the timer applet 'Happytimer', which would explain why no one else has this problem.  Honestly, it did not occur to me that a tea-timer applet would be this intrusive...then again, it's right there in the settings.  I found the culprit by looking in the /usr/share/sounds directory.